# Can I drag and hover then drag with UI Automation?

Tags: ios, ios-ui-automation

In our app there is an action where the user can drag a view to a region of the screen, wait a little bit for a scrollview to page, then drag the view somewhere else and drop it. It's similar to how app icons can be picked up and then dragged to different pages of the Springboard by hovering at the edge of the screen.

Is something like this possible with UI Automation? It looks like the only thing possible is to drag from one point to another, with no pauses in between.